# Java Filelock to prevent multiple writes by multiple JVM processes not working

Tags: java, linux, locking, file-locking

I was learning FileOperations, and was writing a program to implement FileLocking on a linux machine.

- The purpose of this program is, if multiple people invoke the program, the instance should aquire a file lock (Something similar to [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) on a linux system).
- I tried whether my program is working, by running the class file from two different terminal. However, it is returning true each time, thatis, even with the first process running and not releasing the lock, the second process is able to aquire the lock.

My code is

```
    public boolean getLock() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{ 
    File lockFile = new File(conf_file);
    System.out.println("Attempting to aquire"
            + " exclusive lock on " + conf_file);
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(lockFile, "rw");
    FileChannel channel = f.getChannel();
    FileLock lock;
    lock = channel.lock();
    if(lock != null && lock.isValid()){
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        f.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove `f.close()` and try

Comment: Thank you @nohup, it worked. However it now shows a warning in my ide saying resource leak. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: And please write it as the answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `f.close()` method and it should work. To remove the warning in your comment, declare those variables as instance variables and do an f.close in probably another method like `removeLock()`.

Comment: Thank you @nohup but this prevents me from getting read access as well. How can I resolve that?